# How to zoom out Google maps using url link?

Tags: api, google-maps, maps

I want to zoom out this embed code,

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/4529+Rue+Clark+%23300,+Montr%C3%A9al,+QC+H2T+2T3,+Canada/@45.5201216,-73.5878154,20.5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x4cc91bd36faf2391:0x1d8028f635fb35c9!8m2!3d45.5201848!4d-73.5877202" target="_blank">
```

Here is what I have tried,

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/4529+Rue+Clark+%23300,+Montr%C3%A9al,+QC+H2T+2T3,+Canada/@45.5201216,-73.5878154,20.5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x4cc91bd36faf2391:0x1d8028f635fb35c9!8m2!3d45.5201848!4d-73.5877202&z=-10" target="_blank">
```

Comment: It's not an embed code btw, but why don't you zoom out with the controls on the map and just copy that link?

Comment: @rocknrollcanneverdie: I want the users to be able to easily see the address without having to zoom out themselves.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm saying, you need to zoom out the view, and use that link, like this: https://www.google.com/maps/place/4529+Rue+Clark+%23300,+Montr%C3%A9al,+QC+H2T+2T3,+Canada/@45.5201216,-73.6050513,14z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x4cc91bd36faf2391:0x1d8028f635fb35c9!8m2!3d45.5201848!4d-73.5877202

Comment: @rocknrollcanneverdie: Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Also, how did you zoom out?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this just zoom out with the controls on the Google Maps site. You will have a visual clue about the zoom level as well. So you need to set the desired zoom level and use that link (copy from the address bar or use the share function on the site).

[image: Zoom controls]

The `z` parameter no longer works, the zoom level is controlled by the `{n}z` part of the URL. For example a level 10 zoom:

```
@45.5201216,-73.6575797,**10z**
```

The zoom can be between ~1 and ~21 (depends on the current map I think).